# Error on newly added checkbox when submitting form by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can't submit delete ajax script with newly added checkboxes by another ajax script without refreshing the page. Like serialize doesn't see them

```
$('input:submit.delete-checked-categories').on('click', function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'delete-selected-categories',
                data: $('form.categories').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('div#alert').html('Done!');
                    $('div#alert').animate({top: '100'}, 'fast');
                    $('div#alert').fadeIn(300);
                    $('div#alert').delay(200).fadeOut(300);
                    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest("tr").remove();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('div#alert').html('Error!');
                    $('div#alert').animate({top: '100'}, 'fast');
                    $('div#alert').fadeIn(300);
                    $('div#alert').delay(200).fadeOut(300);
                }
            });
        });
```

This is how my submit input jquery script looks like.

I can check many checkboxes, press it, and deletes all in DB and rows from table. But I can add in this form new rows with new inputs, by this script below

```
$('input[name="new-category"]').on('click', function(form) {
            form.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add-category-in-categories',
                data: $('form.categories').serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('div#alert').html('Done!');
                    $('div#alert').animate({top: '100'}, 'fast');
                    $('div#alert').fadeIn(300);
                    $('div#alert').delay(200).fadeOut(300);
                    $('table.table1 > tbody:last-child').append(data);

                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    $('div#alert').html('Error!');
                    $('div#alert').animate({top: '100'}, 'fast');
                    $('div#alert').fadeIn(300);
                    $('div#alert').delay(200).fadeOut(300);
                }
            });
        });
```

table look like...

```
...
<tr id="row-32">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="32" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projekt2/admin/post?id=32">11</a> (0)                 </td>
                    <td>
                        111                 </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-33">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="33" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projekt2/admin/post?id=33">222</a> (0)                    </td>
                    <td>
                        222                 </td>
                </tr>
                                <tr id="row-11">
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="11" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://localhost/projekt2/admin/post?id=11">dfgdfgsfdgdfg</a> (1)                  </td>
                    <td>
                        sdgfgdgfdgfdgfdgdfgdfg                  </td>
                </tr>
...
```

The problem is, that newly added checkbox I can't submit without refreshing the page. Because script alerts `Error` and nothing happens It's like `data: $('form.categories').serialize(),` doesn't see new added checkboxes

[image]

How it looks after adding new tr with checkbox that I can't delete:
[image]

And html:

```
<tr>
        <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="35" checked="checked">

        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="http://localhost/projekt2/admin/category?id=35">tyuyt</a>
        </td>
        <td>
        uytuytu
        </td>
        </tr>
```

Without ajax and jquery, doing just form post request on var_dump of this "category[]" with only checked newly added category I got "NULL" value

This input is in table. whole table is inside form. Works great, but not without refreshing the page.

Script in php:

```
echo json_encode('<tr>
        <td>
        '.form_checkbox(array('name' => 'category[]', 'value' => $category['id'], 'checked' => 'checked')).'
        </td>
        <td>
        '.anchor('admin/category?id='.$category['id'], $category['nazwa']).'
        </td>
        <td>
        '.$category['opis'].'
        </td>
        </tr>');
```

Comment: My guess would be that you managed to place your dynamically added checkboxes outside of the form ... but we have not been shown the form or the table, so rather impossible to say.

Comment: They are inside the form. Whole table is in the form @CBroe

Comment: Well that would be the only possible explanation for “serialize doesn't see them” I can think of. But with the code fragments you have shown, it is hard to tell. Can you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: Ok, I got a bug in your script. when you send a request to get a new row you set the dataType to json but you can't append json formatted data to html, thats's why the error occurs...

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad I don't think that is it, because it appends good row, it's good formated row, besides ajax it doesn't work even with standard form post request - NULL from category[]

Comment: Can you please tell what does error say in console?

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad There is no error, look, now i deleted ajax script for submitting (not adding new row) and is going standard POST form request to php script. And `caregory[]` for this newly added checked button input on var_dump is - `NULL`